# Strange 301 redirect behaviour

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, 301-redirect

The 301 is redirecting but it is appending the old url onto the end of the new url, like so:

http://www.example.co.uk/new-dir/new-page/?/old-dir/old-page/

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /old-dir/old-page/ http://www.example.co.uk/new-dir/new-page/
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `mod_alias` for your redirect; they're not operating in the order that you're expecting based on the order you've put them in in the file.  The query string added to the redirect location is coming from that last `RewriteRule`.

Replace your `Redirect` line:

```
RewriteRule ^old-dir/old-page/?$ http://www.example.co.uk/new-dir/new-page/ [R=301,L]
```

This is assuming your htaccess context is the document root.